# AppEngine & BigQuery - Where would you put stat/monitoring data?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I have an AppEngine application that process files from Cloud Storage and inserts them in BigQuery.

Because now and also in the future I would like to know the sanity/performance of the application... I would like to store stats data in either Cloud Datastore or in a Cloud SQL instance.

I have two questions I would like to ask:

1. Cloud Datastore vs Cloud SQL - what would you use and why? What downsides have you experienced so far?
2. Would you use a `task` or `direct call to insert data` and, also, why? - Would you add a task and then have some consumers insert to data or would you do a direct insert [ regardless of the solution choosen above ]. What downsides have you experienced so far?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Cloud SQL is better if you want to perform JOINs or SUMs later, Cloud Datastore will scale more if you have a lot of data to store. Also, in the Datastore, if you want to update a stats entity transactionally, you will need to shard or you will be limited to 5 updates per second.
2. If the data to insert is small (one row to insert in BQ or one entity in the datastore) then you can  do it by a direct call, but you must accept that the call may fail. If you want to retry in case of failure, or if the data to insert is big and it will take time, it is better to run it asynchronously in a task. Note that with tasks,y you must be cautious because they can be run more than once.

Comment: I'd just add that if you're just logging stats and monitoring data, that is a great use case for bigquery streaming inserts.

Comment: @JordanTigani is right, assuming that you have a lot of data. I would say that the threshold to decide to move to Big Query is around 1TB / 1G row, what do you say Jordan ?

Comment: BigQuery is designed to be size-invariant. Unless you need very fast (sub-second) queries, it is completely reasonable to use with much smaller data sizes. This is especially true if you have append-only data, such as logs, stats, or monitoring data. There are a number of biquery customers who use much smaller data sets and find that bigquery is nearly free to use.

Comment: @JordanTigani what's the response time for the queries on those small datasets? BQ is still too slow to compete with other solutions when it comes to our (viz) projects, e.g. look at bime: that's insanely slow and seeing all those loaders for 10s is not acceptable for our company.

Comment: We're tracking a number of performance issues right now, largely due to usage growth. An example query that I was testing out the other day took 16 seconds in the web UI. The good news is that it only took .8 seconds in the query engine, the rest of the time was spent in queues and in other work. This is good news because we should be able to reduce this time significantly.